# get first letter of string, disregarding "the"

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a list of book titles that begin with a certain letter. However, I need to disregard "the" at the beginning of the title. For instance, when I'm looking for titles that begin with "a", this query should return both "the alamo" and "american history".

How can I do this?

Comment: Not too good with SQL, but you can always comb through each title and, if the first letter is "the", ignore it and check the first letter of the next word within the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
WHERE CASE WHEN SUBSTR(title, 1, 4) = 'the ' THEN SUBSTR(title, 5) ELSE title END LIKE '...'
```

in your query, or use patterns.

Answer (score 2):

try this **Query**

```
select titles
from tablename
where titles like 'a%'
or titles like 'the a%'
```

**Edit**

```
select titles
from tablename
where REPLACE(titles,'the ','') like 'a%'
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't work for the letter "t".

Comment: @GordonLinoff I would like to know what you want to say.Can u please explain.

Comment: You will match titles like "The Alamo" on the letter "T".  I don't think the OP wants this match.

Comment: we can use **LOWER()** And `SQL Server` is not **case sensitive**

Comment: @dmr you can also use **`where REPLACE(titles,'the ','') like 'abc%'`**

Answer (score 2):

```
... where title like 'a%' or title like 'the a%'
```